# JQuery Ajax post request to Spring mvc controller doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

html form:

```
<form action="/account/username" id="change-username-form" method="post">
                <p>
                    <label class="sr-only mb-1" for="current-username">Current Username</label>
                    <input autofocus class="form-control" id="current-username" name="current-username"
                           placeholder="Current Username" required type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="sr-only mb-1" for="new-username">New Username</label>
                    <input autofocus class="form-control" id="new-username" name="new-username"
                           placeholder="New Username" required type="text">
                </p>
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

jquery ajax:

```
$("#change-username-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const form = $(this)
    const url = form.attr("action")
    $.ajax(url, {
        dataType: JSON,
        type: "Post",
        data: {
            changeUsernameDTO: {
                currentUsername: $("#current-username").val(),
                newUsername: $("#new-username").val()
            }
        }
    })
})
```

dto:

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ChangeUsernameDTO {
    private String currentUsername, newUsername;
}
```

spring mvc controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AccountController {

    private final AccountService accountService;

    @PostMapping(
            path = "/username",
            consumes = "application/json"
    )
    public void changeUsername(Authentication authentication, @RequestBody ChangeUsernameDTO dto) {
        accountService.changeUsername(authentication, dto);
    }
}
```

the idea is to have jquery stop the default html form submission, have ajax do it by sending a json object as data that will be catched by spring in a dto

```
2022-10-23 11:40:29.971  WARN 3123 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported]
```

i get this log where it looks like data isn't even sent as json

Comment: if my answer helps request you to please accept it, so that it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refactor your AJAX call like this. It will work.

```js
var object = { currentUsername: $("#current-username").val(),
               newUsername: $("#new-username").val()
             }

$("#change-username-form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const form = $(this)
    const url = form.attr("action")
    $.ajax(url, {
        dataType: JSON,
        type: "Post",
        data: JSON.stringify(object),
        contentType: “application/json”
    })
})
```